# How to fix corrupted imported online excel in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need this online excel:
https://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0

in my google sheet but when I use Importdata formula as below:
Importdata("https://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0")

it turns out to be imported in corrupted way like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99oXB.png)

but the original online file is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fmSn.png)

How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values from the XLSX data downloaded from an URL to the active sheet of Google Spreadsheet.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, it seems that there are no method for directly retrieving the data from XLSX data of URL in the built-in functions for Google Spreadsheet. So in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. When Google Apps Script is used, your goal can be achieved.

The flow of the sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve XLSX data.
2. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet as the temporal Spreadsheet.
3. Retrieve values from the converted Spreadsheet.
4. Put the values from the converted Spreadsheet to the active sheet.
5. Remove the temporal Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Spreadsheet. Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And please run the function of `myFunction` at the script editpor. By this, the values of XLSX data are put to the active sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve XLSX data.
  const url = "https://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0"; // This is your URL.
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();

  // 2. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet as the temporal Spreadsheet.
  const id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, blob).id;

  // 3. Retrieve values from the converted Spreadsheet.
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();

  // 4. Put the values from the converted Spreadsheet to the active sheet.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  // 5. Remove the temporal Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
}
```

- If you want to put the values to the specific sheet and range, please modify the script of `4. Put the values from the converted Spreadsheet to the active sheet.`.

#### References:

- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: thanks. I have copied this script but faced with an error: 11:20:38 AM Error 
ReferenceError: Drive is not defined
myFunction @ Code.gs:7

Comment: I guess because of not enabling drive API

Comment: @Morteza Jafari Amard Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When you use this sample script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. You can see how to enable Drive API at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). After you enabled Drive API, please test it again.

Comment: @Morteza Jafari Amard Thank you for replying. I could understand your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.